# Python acces to right value for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have :

```
data = [ {"Bucket": "test", "MountPoint": "/data"}, {"Bucket": "test2", "MountPoint": "/data2"} ]
```

I use this loop to access to my value `Bucket` and `MountPoint` in a list.

```
my_vals = [val for d in data for val in d.values()]

>>> print(my_vals)
['/data', 'test', '/data2', 'test2']
```

But with this I put `Bucket` and `MountPoint` in my list. And now, how can I just put in my list only `MountPoint` by modifying my for ?

Thank you !

Comment: `[entry['MountPoint'] for entry in data.items()]` perhaps?

Comment: @jasonharper (and upvoter) -- how will that work? (as `list` doesn't have a `.items()` method).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A list comprehension (iterating over the dicts) is one possibility:

```
data = [ {"Bucket": "test", "MountPoint": "/data"}, {"Bucket": "test2", "MountPoint": "/data2"} ]

buckets = [d["Bucket"] for d in data]      # ['test', 'test2']
mpoints = [d["MountPoint"] for d in data]  # ['/data', '/data2']
```

Comment: just to add that `d["Bucket"]` can be replaced with `d.get("Bucket", None)` to handle case of missing key

Comment: @buran True, or even just `d.get("Bucket")` as `None` is the default default (lol) for `dict.get()`.

Comment: @yeah, you a right, None is default. Just to make it more clear to OP - they can replace with something else if they prefer

Answer (score -1):

https://ideone.com/XR1qOk

```
data = [ {"Bucket": "test", "MountPoint": "/data"}, {"Bucket": "test2", "MountPoint": "/data2"} ]

my_vals = [d["MountPoint"] for d in data] 

print(my_vals)
```